# Assigning values to missing data for use in binary logistic regression in SAS

Tags: variables, sas, regression, modeling, missing-data

Many of the variables in the data I use on a daily basis have blank fields, some of which, have meaning (ex. A blank response for a variable dealing with the ratio of satisfactory accounts to toal accounts, thus the individual does not have any accounts if they do not have a response in this column, whereas a response of 0 means the individual has no satisfactory accounts).

Currently, these records do not get included into logistic regression analyses as they have missing values for one or more fields. Is there a way to include these records into a logistic regression model?

I am aware that I can assign these blank fields with a value that is not in the range of the data (ex. if we go back to the above ratio variable, we could use 9999 or -1 as these values are not included in the range of a ratio variable (0 to 1)). I am just curious to know if there is a more appropriate way of going about this. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can impute values for the missing fields, subject to logical restrictions on your experimental design and the fact that it will weaken the power of your experiment some relative to having the same experiment with no missing values.

SAS offers a few ways to do this.  The simplest is to use `PROC MI` and `PROC MIANALYZE`, but even those are certainly not a simple matter of plugging a few numbers in.  See [this page](http://support.sas.com/rnd/app/da/stat/procedures/MultipleImputation.html) for more information.  Ultimately this is probably a better question for Cross-Validated at least until you have figured out the experimental design issues.